# Recursively looping through JSON data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h4kl0rd/4TrdA/3/) with the help from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459917/traversing-through-json-string-to-inner-levels-using-recursive-function). The recursive loop works with JSON raw data but doesn't work when the JSON data is read from PHP array.

```
var notes = '<?php echo json_encode($notes); ?>';

console.log(notes); // displays JSON raw data (used in jsfiddle)
```

After looping through the data, I wanted to get specific output based on type: Subject, Topic, Subtopic, Concept, Paragraph.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: `var notes = <?php echo json_encode($notes); ?>;` ? else it is treated as a string literal not as an object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the quotes: `var notes = <?php echo json_encode($notes); ?>;`

The quotes make it a string, not an object.

If you want to write it as a string, then you need to convert it from the string into JSON:

```
var notes = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($notes); ?>');
```

To access object properties in a for loop, do this:

```
for (var key in myObj) {
  console.log(myObj[key]);
}
```

You can access object propertied with dot notation or bracket notation. Dot notation is often considered to be cleaner, though it is more limited. Consider this object:

```
var myObj = {
  foo : "some value",
  bar : "some other value",
  "1&^@" : "this value's key is invalid!"
};
```

To access the properties that have keys that are valid javascript variable names, you can use dot notation like this:

```
console.log(myObj.foo); //"some value"
console.log(myObj.bar); //"some other value"
```

The third property will not work this way. As it contains otherwise invalid characters, it had to be created as a string and must be accessed as a string, so use bracket notation:

```
console.log(myObj['1&^@']);
```

Another cool thing about bracket notation is that you can use variables as the key name. (also see the for loop above).

```
var foo = 'bar';

var myObj = {
  bar : 123
};

console.log(myObj[foo]); //123
```

This works because `foo` has a value of `'bar'`, so `myObj[foo]` is equivalent to `myObj['bar']` or `myObj.bar`.

Comment: After looping through the values, how do I get content (Physics) based on type (Subject). Eg. {"id":"750","content":"Physics","type":"Subject"}

Comment: I greatly updated my answer. In your answer's example, dot notation would be typically preferred.

Answer (score 0):

With @m59's help I managed to iterate through the JSON data and get specific data. Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h4kl0rd/4TrdA/4/).

```
if (obj['type'] == 'Subject') {
     body += 'SubjectId:' + obj['id'] + '<br>';
     body += 'SubjectContent:' + obj['content'] + '<br>';

     var topics = obj['children'];
     var topic;
     for (topic in topics) {
         body += 'topicId:' + topics[topic]['id'] + '<br>';
         body += 'topicContent:' + topics[topic]['content'] + '<br>';
         body += 'topicType:' + topics[topic]['type'] + '<br>';
     }
}
```