# Extracting data fields from a json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I've been reading all the stuff I can find about this, but none of the solutions seems to provide the answer I need.

Specifically, I read this [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json) carefully, as well as dozens of other posts.

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

I have a large object, called `allData` -- that I got as a json object from MongoDB, and it contains an array of all the data from each reading.

```
{pitch: -7.97, roll: -4.3, temp: 98, yaw: -129.83, time: "01/22/2016 17:28:47", …}
{pitch: -8.04, roll: -4.41, temp: 97, yaw: -130.81, time: "01/22/2016 17:28:58", …}
```

...
What I'd LIKE to do is be able to extract all the pitch readings with something along the lines of `allData.pitch` but obviously that doesn't work, since each data reading is in an element of the `allData` array. So I could go through in a loop and do `allData[x].pitch` but I was hoping for cleaner, faster way to do do this -- since I'll probably want to extract each type of data.

Unfortunately at this point I don't have the ability to simply request the pitch data from the db, so I get this whole set back.

One last wrinkle is that ONE of the elements of the array above is already a data object.

Comment: Likely a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459917/traversing-through-json-string-to-inner-levels-using-recursive-function - if it is, feel free to delete your question

Comment: `var pitches = allData.map(function(o) { return o.pitch; });`

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear in the original question ... I'd like to get back the pitches and the data/time they were recorded so that I can graph them accordingly.

Comment: @Andreas +1 also `allData.map(o => o.pitch)` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilise [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for this

```
var pitches = allData.map(function(d) {
                  return {
                      "pitch": d.pitch,
                      "time": d.time
                  };
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't control the data returned from the server (i.e., to only retrieve the pitch values you want), you are going to have to loop through to get them all.